Node.js executable codesign breaking
I have a node.js server which runs on port 8442. The moment I sign the executable with a Apple certificate using codesign it does not want to bind to the port. I tested on two MacBook's with the same outcome. But when it is unsigned it works just fine.
Installing the service which listens op port 8442 without signing it with a Apple Developer certificate works but a unsigned app throws a bunch of warnings when installed on a client device. When the node.js executable is signed it stops working and does not listen on the required port. Nothing else is running on the port, I checked this. If anyone needs more info or if I missed something in my explanation please let me know.
